# Отображение сообщения после закрытия главного окна

Tags: android

Задача - отобразить пользователю сообщение сразу после закрытия главного окна.
Пытался сделать это в методе `onDestroy()` своего Activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Toast.makeText(me, "Goodbye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Но он ничего не выводит, более того - отладчик туда даже не заходит.
Вопрос: как отобразить пользователю сообщение сразу после закрытия главного окна приложения?

Comment: @lxx, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен метод onStop(), а не onDestroy() [тыц](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)

Answer (score 2):

Метод onDestroy() сработает в том случае если activity уйдет из стека. По умолчанию если вы нажимаете кнопку назад, то activity еще висит в системе и сообщения не будет. Сообщение вы увидите если убьете activity через диспетчер задач, ну или система её убьет при нехватки памяти. Либо принудительно убивайте activity , либо используйте метод onStop(), он вызывается когда activity становится не видимой для пользователя и готова к завершению своего жизненного цикла.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте показывать сообщение в методе onStop()